# Storing and analysis of historical data - What kind of Database?

Tags: mysql, plot, nosql

I'm currently designing a system that watches the ranks / views of youtube videos. of LOTS of youtube videos (> 500.000 and growing) on a daily basis.

I'm currently considering storing this in a MySQL database, but what disturbs me, is that the table would grow into billions and trillions of rows, which I don't think would perform well.

I need to analyse this data, for example:

- Which videos grew a lot in the time between X and Y
- Plot the clicks per day
- Plot the clicks per week ...
- some more things I don't know yet about

So, what came into my web 2.0 mind was, is there a way a NoSQL database could handle this better? I didn't quite learn these (almost) new databases and don't know what they are capable of.

What would your advice be, what type of database to use?
Relational or not? If not, which NoSQL database?

PS: first priority is the fast evaluation and insertion of the results, second is high availability (or just replication)

Comment: considering performance, a sidenote: do you know facbeook is built on MySQL?

Comment: yes, i think i read that at some point. my motivation of this question was primarily my concern about "too large tables" (not clustered) and a fast evaluation of that historical data. i'm currently experimenting on mysql, but i'm not sure if it's the right thing to choose.

Comment: honestly, if only too large tables are your prior concern, I don't think you'll have to worry, if: you can use indexes to narrow down your search results. Indexes are used as row pointers, so the number of rows won't hurt the index, it just simply points to those right rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very difficult to give an advice for a database system, because it always depends. However, considering that Facebook is built on MySQL, it shows that there probably performance is not a limit on MySQL for you.

What is helpful and you'll probably have done, is creating a structure of how your table structure should look like. Then also think of queries you would like to run against the tables.

If you have the right indexes (which is the main and crucial factor query speed relies on), you will not have to worry about performance in MySQL. What you should consider are (what I've had to experience), that there are many interesting things how MySQL deals with indexes. Let me give a few examples I had to figure out during the time:

- if you want to use an index for a range scan, the index cannot be used for `ORDER BY` anymore
- a range column has to be the last in an concatenated index for the full index to be used, same for `ORDER BY` again

For more information, a useful link on mysqlperformanceblog.com: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/

In general, if the structure of the database is well thought and the indexing is good, in my experience it does not matter actually if you only have 10.000 rows or 10 billion, the query time would be about the same.